# Difference between as was expected and as was to be expected

Tags: grammar

Please tell me what is the difference between as was expected and as was to be expected below.

1. A good many proposals were raised by the delegates, as *was expected*.
2. A good many proposals were raised by the delegates, as *was to be expected*.

Thank you

Comment: I think 'was' should be left out both cases, and actually I was wondering that difference but I guess it is not that meaningful.

Comment: [*As was expected* is definitely the most common of the three](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+expected%2Cas+was+expected%2Cas+was+to+be+expected&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20expected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20was%20expected%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cas%20was%20to%20be%20expected%3B%2Cc0), but I wouldn't go so far as to call the others wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**as was expected** means "as people expected".

**as was to be expected** means "as there was reason to expect"

P.S. Consider this scenario:

**The hairline crack propagated and the turbine blade failed, as was to be expected.**

That is, there is reason to expect any turbine blade to fail if it has a hairline crack which propagates. That is *the usual result* when a crack in metal is subject to further stress. There is no implication that people had advance knowledge of this particular crack.

**The hairline crack propagated and the turbine blade failed, as was expected.**

This would imply that there was knowledge, in advance, that the blade had a crack, and that it was expected to fail; people were waiting for the blade to fail.

Comment: Tomato I didn't understand your explanation for the second sentence. Could you explain it in some more detail?

Comment: Koala, I have added a P.S.